# How to center text at the bottom of the page with css?

Tags: html, css, css-position

I am trying to place some text at the **bottom-center** of an html page but it is not aligned.

```css
main {
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    max-width: 240px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.bottom {
    position:fixed;
    bottom:0;
}
```

```html
<main>
    <div>
        <h1>Hello</h1>
    </div>
    <div class=bottom>
        <span>Bottom text</span>
    </div>
</main>
```

I have tried various options including *position:absolute;* (text not at bottom) and *margin: 0 auto;* in bottom css (no effect)

What am I missing?

Comment: It seems you want to give `.bottom` a `width`. https://jsfiddle.net/TRNCFRMCN/y9h4v8q7/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ensure that the bottom  spans the full width of its parent container, occupying 100% of the available horizontal space. When setting its position to fixed at the bottom of its relative parent, make sure the  starts from the left corner and extends horizontally to cover the entire width of the parent container.

```css
main {
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  max-width: 240px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.bottom {
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <div>
    <h1>Hello</h1>
  </div>
  <div class=bottom>
     <span>Bottom text</span>
  </div>
</main>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `left: 50%;` and `transform: translateX(-50%);` to `bottom` to center it. `left: 50%;` moves the left edge of the element to the middle of its container and `transform: translateX(-50%);` moves it back to the left by 50% of its own width – those two in combination center it horizontally.

```css
main {
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    max-width: 240px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.bottom {
    position:fixed;
    bottom:0;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
}
```

```html
<main>
    <div>
        <h1>Hello</h1>
    </div>
    <div class=bottom>
        <span>Bottom text</span>
    </div>
</main>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
main {
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    max-width: 240px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    height: 100vh;
}

.bottom {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 50%; 
    transform: translateX(-50%);
 
}

<main>
    <div>
        <h1>Hello</h1>
    </div>
    <div class=bottom>
        <span>Bottom text</span>
    </div>
</main>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `display: flex` (makes it independent from `text-align: center` on `main`):

```css
main {
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    max-width: 240px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.bottom {
    position:fixed;
    bottom:0;
    /* solution with flexbox: */
    display: flex;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<main>
    <div>
        <h1>Hello</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="bottom">
        <span>Bottom text</span>
    </div>
</main>
```